# GCC section attribute on function implementation

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm

Can I use `__attribute__((section("name")))` on a function implementation like this:

```
int __attribute__((section("name"))) Foo( void )
{
   return 1;
}
```

This works on arm compiler, see this link http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124977848.htm

Would GCC ignore the section attribute when it is used only on the function implementation and not the prototype?

Comment: [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) say: *Compatible attribute specifications on distinct declarations of the same function are merged. An attribute specification that is not compatible with attributes already applied to a declaration of the same function is ignored with a warning.*

Comment: The docs say: "Function attributes are introduced by the __attribute__ keyword in the declaration of a function, followed by an attribute specification enclosed in double parentheses" and I understand that but I am just wondering if GCC specifically ignore section attribute on function implementations.

Comment: A function implementation also *includes* a declaration, AFAIR.

Comment: maybe in this code example, what if the function was declared in .h file somewhere else?

Comment: I would imagine it will do what the documentation says, provided the header is properly included everywhere the function is used or implemented. If you declare the function in a header that is not included by the implementing .c file, and that declaration has attributes that are not used on the implementation, I suspect everything will break spectacularly at some point.

Comment: @EOF: Why should it break? Only the implementing module needs to tell the linker which section to use. To calling modules it's just an address.

Comment: @TonyK you can set some fairly interesting attributes on functions, some of which constitute contracts that can't otherwise be specified in C. If the caller believes the function conforms to the contract, and the function doesn't, then arbitrary breakage is possible.

Comment: @EOF: I think we are talking about different things here. My comment was about the `section("name")` attribute, whereas it seems that you were talking about function attributes in general.